# OpenLayers 3 example works in Chrome, but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I followed the quick start example [here](http://ol3js.org/en/master/doc/quickstart.html), and it works in Chrome but not in Firefox (v29). Firebug isn't reporting any errors. I literally just copied and pasted the source into an `index.html` file, so there's not a lot of room for human error.

Specifically, the map isn't initializing. There are zoom buttons and an `h2`, but otherwise a blank white screen. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Strange. I can confirm this is an issue in Firefox, but works on Chrome, on Ubuntu too. I don't see any errors in console either. I will have a look at this on the dev build of OL3 when I get home, as on another box.

Comment: We're you ever able to fix this issue. I'm getting the same thing!

Comment: Kind of. You can find a solution [here](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2118).